# Is it possible to customize how jQuery serializes AJAX url parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to tell jQuery/an AJAX call to format query string parameters in a specific way, other than just writing my own serializer?

I have a jQuery AJAX call, and am passing an object containing URL parameters

`var params = {name: 'somename', favColors: ['red','blue']};`

Inspecting the AJAX call `$.get("/Controller/Action/", params)` shows that the URL param string is `?name=somename&favColors[]=red&favColors[]=blue`

The target URL expects the query params to not contain [] for the repeated array values, e.g. `?name=somename&favColors=red&favColors=blue`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) and its 2nd argument, `traditional`, providing that result to `$.get()`:

```
var params = {name: 'somename', favColors: ['red','blue']};

$.get("/Controller/Action/", $.param(params, true))
```

The argument is described as:

> A Boolean indicating whether to perform a traditional "shallow" serialization.

In this case:

```
console.log($.param(params, true));
// "name=somename&favColors=red&favColors=blue"
```

Comment: never stopped to figure out what `traditional` was, I guess since I've never needed it...makes my answer look silly now

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of solution I was after!

Answer (score 0):

[`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) also accepts a query string as second argument instead of an object. You can use that to append your custom-generated query string. The `?` gets appended for you so you don't need to put one.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to form encode the data string from objects. You could use it yourself and remove the `[]` which get encoded as `%5B%5D`.

As noted in other answer string can be used as well as object for data argument

Something like:

```
var reg =/%5B%5D/g;
var params= $.param({name: 'somename', favColors: ['red','blue']}).replace(reg,'');
$.get("/Controller/Action/", params)
```

Tested in browser console only